# Did Krypton have contact with other civilizations?

Tags: dc, superman, krypton

In every incarnation of the Superman story I've ever seen (comics, movies, cartoons etc), Krypton is depicted as a technologically and culturally advanced civilization.

In some cases it is outright stated that they had mastered interstellar travel and colonized other worlds while other versions only imply this fact (Kal-El's ship is fairly advanced).

Is there any canon information that shows ancient Kryptonians having any kind of diplomatic or political contact with other space faring races? Were they aware of the Green Lantern Core, the Ancient Martians, Thanagarians etc?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4Hnw.png - The Lantern Corp were aware of Krypton, but not the other way around (at least in the original Superman comics)

Comment: This is really broad. There are literally dozens of continuities that feature Superman. The most recent Supergirl TV show has Krypton ruling an empire that contains hundreds of different space-faring races, for example.

Comment: After 80 some years of different creative time periods where continuity was completely secondary to the plot and more modern re-re-(re-)reboots, that's a tricky one to answer. Most depictions of Krypton either favour they weren't into space exploration or their space exploration period was centuries ago.  Generally, a reason is needed why only Kal-El's rocket was available rather than a fleet.  AND, Kal-El's rocket is often depicted as a prototype invented by Jor-El, which why it was only large enough for a baby.

Comment: @Valorum: is this question perhaps just asking about the comics (so only 80-odd years of continuity then), given that it mentions the Green Lantern Corps as an example?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite  - Except that the GLC appears in various TV shows as well

Comment: @Valorum: and two beloved feature films!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Supergirl tv series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergirl_(TV_series)) (which may or may not be considered canon), Krypton had extensive contact with its sister planet in its solar system, from which Mon-El hails.

In the comics, the original Mon-El was an explorer named Lar Gand from the plant Daxam (not in the same solar system as Krypton) who visited Krypton shortly before it was destroyed, met Superman's father Jor-El, who directed him to Earth. So Krypton had *some* contact with other civilizations right before the end.

In general in the comics, Krypton has been described as rather xenophobic as an explanations for why they didn't travel to the stars.

Comment: Technically Dax-em was a Kryptonian colony that had interbred with the local intelligent (but otherwise unremarkable) species